# Jquery, Extract child text

Tags: jquery

Here is html code,

```
<li class="comment-content">
    Target String!!!
    <span class="comment-time">2011-07-13 17:08:39</span>
    <a title="comment" class="bottoml cof-comment" href="#">comment</a>
    <a title="modify" class="bottoml cof-comment" href="#">modify</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a title="delete" class="bottoml cof-comment" href="#">delete</a></li>
</li>
```

I can get comment-content's text using jquery like this,

```
$(".comment-content").text();
```

the result is :

```
Target String!!! 2011-07-13 17:08:39 comment modify delete
```

my question, can I get the string "Target String!!!" only using jquery?
without sub tag's text, direct child text only I mean.

Comment: If the Target String text was in a <p> tag it would be easy, can that happen? Or is that not possible?

Comment: hmm... I know of that, but this html code is fixed. ^^;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('.comment-content').contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 3; });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/FGAXE/

As you can see on the [MDN Node.nodeType explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType), the constant TEXT_NODE = 3, so that's what we need to look for.

Comment: Yep, only way I've ever seen it done. Maybe we can get a `.nodeType('TEXT_NODE')` feature in a future JQuery release ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hope it will work

```
var content = $(".comment-content").html();
var targetString = content.substring(0,content.indexOf('<'))
```

`targetString` is you required.

Answer (score 0):

Another Trick:

> ```
>                 $(this)
>                     .clone()
>                     .children()
>                     .remove()
>                     .end()
>                     .text();
> ```